# VKAPI_ATTR and VKAPI_CALL macros in Vulkan

Tags: c++, vulkan

I have been searching and I still am not sure **what** `VKAPI_ATTR` and `VKAPI_CALL` are. I am not sure if they are suppose to be a macro or some fancy C++ function declaration I am not aware of.

What is `VKAPI_ATTR void VKAPI_CALL vkCommand(void)` offering that `void vkCommand(void)` doesn't offer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are macros to make sure the correct calling convention is applied. This is less important in 64 bit where they have mostly converged but in 32 bit there are several incompatible ones.

Unfortunately different compilers have different ways of doing that. One puts the required token before the return value the other puts it after.

So the header uses both to make sure it can cover all bases.

Comment: So this is a C/C++ feature?

Comment: no, but this does https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html

Comment: neither of them does, because none of them specify when you need the macro when you are designing something, they only say vk needs them.

Answer (score 5):

They are defined in [vk_platform.h](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/blob/1.0/src/vulkan/vk_platform.h).

They are C preprocessor macros that expand to platform-dependent (and often compiler-specific) function attributes.

The [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#_platform_specific_calling_conventions) defines what they are supposed to do.
But basically each of `VKAPI_ATTR`, `VKAPI_CALL` and `VKAPI_PTR` is distiguished by the spot it has to be in the function declaration to satisfy the C (potentially compiler-dependent) syntax.
Their value(s) are things like the chosen *calling convention* (e.g. `__stdcall`) for the platform (detected at compile time).

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find that Spec page