# multiple return values Vulkan C++ function header

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm reading the tutorial on the Vulkan API.  There is a function which seems to me to be declaring 3 return types.  I'm not sure if this is a C++ feature or something unique to Vulkan.

```
static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(
  VkDebugReportFlagsEXT flags,
  VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT objType,
  uint64_t obj,
  size_t location,
  int32_t code,
  const char* layerPrefix,
  const char* msg,
  void* userData) {
    std::cerr << "validation layer: " << msg << std::endl;

    return VK_FALSE;
}
```

I saw this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668656/vkapi-attr-and-vkapi-call-macros-in-vulkan), but it doesn't really explain what is going on here.

Comment: Actually that answer is pretty clear, x86 has different calling conventions, those macros ensure that the correct ones are used so there isn't stack corruption.

Comment: The only actual return type seems to be `VkBool32`. The other are probably macros that expand to compiler-specific keywords or attributes regarding the function itself.

Comment: Just ignore the `VKAPI_*` macros if you're not sure what they do - they are _not_ return types, they just tell the compiler how this function should be called and/or compiled.

Comment: the answer you link indeed does explain what is going on. Imho you should ask there for clarification rather than creating a duplicate question

Comment: Use the `-E` compiler option to see the code after macros are expanded, to see what they do.

Comment: Or just search for `VKAPI_ATTR`, which took me [straight to the declarations](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/external/vulkan/vk_platform.h) (or some version of them). You can see they're compiler-specific and platform-specific extensions.

Comment: In fact the second answer to your linked question already links to a better (more official) copy of the same code. Read it! If you're still confused, then look up the `__stdcall` MSVC extension, or the `__attribute__((pcs("aapcs-vfp")))` GCC extension, or whatever

Comment: following this trail, I see that __attribute__((pcs("aapcs-vfp")))  is for ARM processor optimization...is this correct?

Comment: For me, this is not the duplicate, because all of your comments have led me to the following answer: VKAPI_ATTR is defined as __attribute__((pcs("aapcs-vfp"))).  Then the answer that satisfied me is on https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html which states this is an ARM function attribute.

Answer (score 0):

some implementations of c/c++ compilers accept certain attributes for different functions and structs, i.e. optimization level for the function, or marking it as a specific purpose. They usually do not change the functionality but might add or remove special code or use special calling convention or whatever. So, common practice is to hide attributes int macros, defined in some header files.

In your case both `VKAPI_ATTR` and `VKAPI_CALL` look like such macros specific to the Vulkan. In other implementations they are defined to nothing, but in your case they might have some meaning. Check header files for their definition.

The bottom line is that there is only a **single** return type `VkBool32`, the rest are just attributes.